# Safe to remove leading or trailing .* from regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex

To answer the question whether a pattern can be find inside a string. (`true` or `false` answer only. Where or how many is not a concern.)

Assuming the regex pattern does not contain possessive repetitions, is it always safe to remove trailing or leading `.*` and `.*?` from the pattern string? For example, `find('.*blah.*', x)` is guaranteed to return the same result as `find('blah', y)`.

If the answer to the first question is "no", what if only syntax in [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) is allowed in the regex pattern?

Comment: You can remove `.*` *unless* the pattern in *find* is anchored by default. Is  `find` anchoring the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [RE2 docs](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax):

> any character, **possibly including newline *(s=true)***  `.`

and then

> `s`    let `.` match `\n` (**default *false***)

So, `.*` matches zero or more characters other than a newline.

Without the `/s` modifier, the leading `.*` will find zero or more characters other than a newline on the same line with `blah`, up to the last `blah`. With `/s`, it will find all the substring from the start of a string until the last `blah` in the string. When you omit the leading `.*`, the regex engine will just try to match the first `blah` in the string.

*If* `find` *does not anchor the pattern*, it is safe to omit it on both ends, and `find('.*blah.*', x)` will yield the same ***boolean*** results as `find('blah', y)`. Else, it will not. The ***string*** results might differ.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was more worried out situations like `.*?`, where removing `.*` will leave me with a `?`, which alter the meaning of the regex. I think I didn't emphasize that enough in my question. Additionally, sorry for not responding earlier.

Comment: The  `.*?` pattern matches any characters before the first occurrence of the subsequent subpattern where backtracking allows it. You should only remove it if you know that a follows b immediately. Same goes about .*, it only matches up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpattern.